# Is there any symmetric formula for numerical calculation of the second order derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

I know about these formulas:
$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$
$$f''(x)≈\frac{f(x+Δx)−2\,f(x)+f(x-Δx)}{Δx^2}$$

But I'm interested in the numerical formula for the second order derivative without element $−2\,f(x)$ in it (because I need to calculate the second order derivative of the table given function in the point that missed in table and without any Newton or Taylor approximations before it).

Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Let's imagine I have $(0; 1)$, $(1; 2)$, $(2; 3)$ points of function and need to find out  the second order derivative at the point 0.5. How could I do it?

Comment: That would be problematic, since you have continuum twice-differentiable functions passing through any 3 given points...

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that is the task from the exam and I don't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: IF you know the second derivative at some neighbouring point you could just rearrange the above equation and insert for $f(x)$.

Comment: The only thing that I have is the table and point.

Comment: FYI: I deleted my earlier answer because I realised it was bollocks. I apologise.

Comment: That's okay, thank you for help anyway.

Comment: approximate $f'(0.5)$ and $f'(1.5)$ then approximate second derivative using your first formula

Comment: @Noerig The three points you propose are co-linear... A possible guess would be a null second derivative. (this leads to the same result as Vasili's suggestion).